# Long Compilation Time: Tikz Accents

Tags: compiling, accents

Throughout my thesis, I have accent several mathematical symbols with "hats" and "checks". My advisor noted that the standard `\hat{}, \check{}` accents were difficult to read due to their size, so I made my own in Tikz. However, now LaTeX takes several (around three) minutes to compile the entire document.

Below is the code used to define these symbols. I do use the `accents` package. Is there a more efficient way to define custom accents for mathematical symbols? I imagine Tikz is running every time the compiler comes across my command which is what's slowing it down, but I'm not sure how to avoid this. I am using TexMaker with the latest MikTex distribution for Windows.

```
% Some symbols 

\newcommand{\myhat}{%
\mathbin{\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 0.15pt, smooth]
\draw[smooth, fill] (0,0.1ex) -- ({0.5ex - 0.3pt},0.45ex) -- ({0.5ex + 0.3pt},0.45ex) -- (1ex, 0.1ex) -- (0.5ex ,0.4ex) -- (0,0.1ex);
\draw[white](0,0ex) -- (0, 0.1);
\end{tikzpicture} 
}}

\newcommand \what [1]{
\accentset{\myhat}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\mycheck}{%
\mathbin{\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 0.15pt, smooth]
\draw[smooth, fill, rotate = 180] (0,0.1ex) -- ({0.5ex - 0.3pt},0.45ex) -- ({0.5ex + 0.3pt},0.45ex) -- (1ex, 0.1ex) -- (0.5ex ,0.4ex) -- (0,0.1ex);
\draw[white](0,-0.5ex) -- (0, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}}

\newcommand \wcheck [1]{
\accentset{\mycheck}{#1}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the tikz pictures in a savebox.

```
\newsavebox\myhat
\savebox\myhat{\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand\what[1]{\accentset{\mathbin{\usebox\myhat}}{#1}}
```